# Мобильная адаптация

Tags: html, css

Почему, мобильная адаптация не правильно отображается, может где ошибся, помогите пожалуйста!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Rubik" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.png" type="image/png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Вот ссылка http://daniilkrylov.ru/

Comment: а что там именно неправильно?

Comment: @flowskill, да, уточни вопрос пожалуйста ;)